# inline-block div still moving to next line

Tags: html, css

I have blocks of images with the `display: inline-block` property but they are still wrapping to the next line when there is space available. I want it so it sits much like a table of images.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container" style="margin-left:2.5%;width:62.8%;margin-top:7%">
  <div id="dummy"></div>
  <div id="box">
    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container" style="margin-left:2.5%;margin-top:7%">
  <div id="dummy"></div>
  <div id="box">
    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 1.25%;
    margin-right: 1.25%;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

#dummy {
    padding-top: 75%;
}

#box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

#box img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3o31o6x/4/).

Comment: Do you expect a smaller image to share the first row with the larger one?

Comment: a few observations: `id` is meant to be used ONCE per page, so your `id`s should either be renamed or just converted to `classes`. Also, you might want to decide `inline styles` or `stylesheet`. You are overriding #container's width of `30%` with `62.8%`

Comment: Have you tried adding 'position:absolute' for the img tag?because i think that would work

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes that's what I'm going for

Comment: @ShrikanthBuds It doesn't seem to have much effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

- you are setting in inline styles  in the first `#container` a `width:62.8%` therefore the other `div`s wrap into a new line.

---

So if you want all in the same line, and keeping the current `margin`s you have to apply `width:22%` to `.container`

### Notes

- ID's **must** be unique so use class instead
- avoid using inline CSS, instead use in a CSS file

---

**UPDATE**  (OP's Comment)

> The problem is I would like one of the images to be bigger than the
>   others while still keeping the same format so in the end I want a 3x3
>   table with one of the photos taking up 2x2 of the space available

So give a `width:47%` to `container` #1,#4,#7 and so on, using `nth-of-type(3n+1)`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  position: relative;
  width: 22%;
  margin-left: 1.25%;
  margin-right: 1.25%;
  margin-top: 3%;
}
.container:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  width: 47%
}
.dummy {
  padding-top: 75%;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.box img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is I would like one of the images to be bigger than the others while still keeping the same format so in the end I want a 3x3 table with one of the photos taking up 2x2 of the space available

Comment: Is it also possible to have 4 small images next to the larger one instead of just 2? Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @Danster yes it is possible, just set `width:11%` more or less

Comment: I mean as a small table of 2x2 next to the larger one so all up it would look like a 4x2 table where the larger image is taking up 2x2 and 4 smaller images are taking up 2x2 as well.

Comment: if you figure it out please hit me up I need to fix this ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: Im not in computer right now. Can you please make a draw of you want so I can understand perfectly and try to help you better?